# How we send value to text area field using selenium

Tags: selenium

How we send value to text area field using selenium webdriver for this example

```
<div class="col-md-8 blockBox">
    <textarea style="width:100%" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

I tried this two locators but not working:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("col-md-8 blockBox")).sendKeys("adcfv"); 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("col-md-8 blockBox")).sendKeys("adcfv");
```

Comment: Please post the html here.

Answer (score 1):

Your locators aren't quite right, you need to give it a bit more information to work out what you're looking for. Try this for the CSS option:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='col-md-8 blockBox']"))
```

That should locate the Element more successfully, and allow you to interact with it as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Try first focusing to the textarea.

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-8 blockBox']/textarea")).clear(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-8 blockBox']/textarea")).sendKeys(("adcfv");

and it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you will even need to hover over the element to make it clickable. This you can do by this:

```
String mouseOverScript = "if(document.createEvent){var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');evObj.initEvent('mouseover', true, false); arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evObj);} else if(document.createEventObject) { arguments[0].fireEvent('onmouseover');}";
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(mouseOverScript,
                     driver.findElement(By.<your locator>));
```

Then use any locator to send data

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-8 blockBox']/textarea")).sendKeys(("myData");
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me in C#, Try this.

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();//.This line for C# with Selenium

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();//..This line for java with Selenium

driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

//...Below two lines are for C# with Selenium(use, if you are a C# coder)
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.example.com");
diver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

//...Below two lines are for Java with Selenium(use, if you are a Java coder)
driver.get("https://www.expample.com");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;//...for C# Coder

JavaScriptExecutor js = (JavaScriptExecutor)driver;//...for Java Coder

js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('EmpName').value='James Bond';");
```